# Using socket.io with redux-observable (react, rxjs, socket.io)

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, observable, redux-observable

Does anybody have a clean example of combining redux-observable with socket.io?

I want to architect my app so that certain actions are piped into the socket, and data from the socket – which is already in the form of an action – is piped into the reducers.

Comment: You should share what you have tried so far. It makes it much easier to help if you show you have attempted the a solution and just gotten stuck somewhere.

Comment: I gave up on observables (rxjs, cycles, etc), also tried redux-saga which I liked better but gave up on that too, and finally found salvation in react-redux-firebase :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on observables (rxjs, cycles, etc), also tried redux-saga which I liked better but gave up on that too, and finally found salvation in react-redux-firebase :)

Comment: Can you please provide some details on why you gave up on rxjs integration with react-redux app? It is one of the ideas I am toying with to integrate frequent real-time updates in my app

Comment: @2442396 react-redux-firebase works beautifully out of the box, with no fuss. Can't see a reason to use rxjs, except to waste lots of time reinventing the wheel.